# How can I protect my code from sql injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

how can I protect this code from sql injection?

```
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM newidea WHERE tag LIKE '%" . $arrayuser[$i] . "%' AND ID > $number";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: Hi @Dharman , I used mysqli_real_escape_string() function. Do you think it's enough to protect from sql injection? I found different opinions in the Internet. I'll learn PDO, but for now I've done my project in mysql, so I'd like to end it.

Comment: Technically, it should be enough but it is not worth it. Just use prepared statements and forgot about any need to escape. It's safer, easier and quicker.